# Como reformular UI do radio e checkbox?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css3, ux

Estou utilizando radio e checkbox customizados do [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio), percebi que alguns clientes tiveram dificuldades em assimilar que eram checkbox ou radios e que deveriam realizar a ação de selecionados.

### Exemplo:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="text-center">
  <h3>Não sei se todos estão ativados ou desativados</h3>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
      <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked>Android
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
      <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">Windows
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
      <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">iOS
    </label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <h3>Não sei se esta selecionado dois e um não esta  selecionado</h3>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked>Android
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">Windows
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off">iOS
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Conforme o exemplo acima, as vezes o usuário se enrola e acaba realizando uma ação equivocada, como eu poderia deixar mais intuitivo reaproveitando as classes do bootstrap?

Comment: Talvez cores, apesar de "estragar" o seu layout, as cores são mais intuitivas para todos.

Comment: Realmente o "feedback" para o usuário esta bem imperceptível, trocaria a propriedade color do texto para não fugir muito do layout.

Comment: Se passar o `gradient` do botão pra ficar mais claro quando não pressionado ficaria bem fácil de entender. A questão é, não uso bootstrap então não sei onde muda 8D

Comment: Votei por deixar aberta, pois perguntas voltadas ao UX são bem aceitas pela comunidade, e pra quem não sabe UX nunca vai ser "absoluto", então sempre vai cair na ideia de que é baseada em opinião, mas não é, aqui qualquer resposta pode solucionar de diferentes maneiras, mas ainda sim resolvem, não vai ser uma coisa de "eu acho".

Comment: @LuizVieira vou continuar depois no META, mas entendi seu ponto de vista. Depois vou tentar partilhar minha opinião, to apagando os comentários.

Comment: Eu uso vermelho e verde para desativo e ativo respetivamente e é uma maravilha. E são cores que não ficam mal porque já são habituais, on e off, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se analisarmos a semântica dos nomes "check-box" e "radio-button" veremos o seguinte:

- Check-box. Do inglês caixa (*box*) de seleção/marcação (*check*). A ideia tradicional desse tipo de componente é que ele é literalmente uma caixa (um quadrado) que pode ser riscado/marcado para indicar a seleção de um item.
- Radio-button. Do inglês botão (*button*) *radial* (radio). A palavra "radial" talvez seja pouco conhecida, mas tem a mesma raíz de "*dial*" (em inglês, do botão do rádio) e no dicionário consta como "relativa a raio". Significa algo que circula, ou que leva de um ponto a outro atravessando algo (você já ouviu a falar da Avenida Radial Leste aqui em São Paulo?). O componente tem esse nome porque, apesar de também permitir a seleção de itens, os itens são mutuamente exclusivos, de forma que ao se selecionar um novo item automaticamente se desfaz uma seleção prévia. De fato, o nome vem de rádio, pois antigamente os rádios automotivos tinham botões físicos para sintonização, e ao pressionar um deles o anterior pressionado era liberado.

Convencionalmente, esses componentes têm sido projetados para terem em seu design um quadrado no caso do check-box e um círculo no caso do radio-button, que são ambos preenchidos ou não para indicar o estado de selecionado/não-selecionado. A interface que você utiliza na pergunta é uma adaptação mais moderna que permite indicar o estado de seleção por meio de distinção de cores e a "radialidade" (será que eu inventei uma palavra nova?) por meio da unicidade da cor de seleção entre todos os itens.

Mas ela tem alguns problemas (ao menos nessa implementação). Primeiramente, há um baixíssimo contraste de cores entre os estados selecionado/não-selecionado, que seria particularmente grave em ambientes com mais baixa luminosidade (algo relativamente comum para usuários de dispositivos móveis). Eles também não usam a convenção já amplamente estabelecida na interação humano-computador (quadrado é para marcação individual, círculo para seleção em grupo), fazendo com que os usários tenham que reaprender a convenção utilizada.

Entretanto, o problema mais relevante é que esses componentes *não contêm* indicações sensoriais ([affordances](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordance)) sobre o que fazem e/ou como podem ser utilizados. Em um sistema computacional tradicional, em que se utiliza o mouse, o clique é a affordance mais comum. A primeira coisa que um usuários em dúvida vai fazer é tentar clicar num objeto. De forma similar, em um sistema computacional móvel, a affordance mais direta é o toque com os dedos, e a primeira coisa a ser feita vai ser tentar tocar sobre o objeto. Eventualmente o usuário vai aprender como ele funciona interagindo, mas um quadrado ou círculo vazio tem uma affordance visual que já indica que ele possa talvez ser preenchido. Falta esse tipo de affordance nos objetos, e por isso os usuários têm a dificuldade inicial de diferenciá-los de meros botões.

Uma solução para esse problema em particular seria adicionar uma área vazia, que dê a percepção de que ela possa ser preenchida, ou mesmo apenas usar uma simbologia de marcação (o tradicional rabisco de check-list) para inicar que o item está de fato selecionado.

Você pode, por exemplo, usar o pseudo elemento **`:after`** para incluir algum desses símbolos que lembrem uma "marca", como por exemplo: ✅. Aumentar o contraste da cor entre as opções marcadas e desmarcadas também é importante, pois as destacaria em muitos dos casos (e, principalmente, em relação a usuários daltônicos). Exemplo de implementação:

```css
.btn        { background: #ccc !important; border: none !important }
.btn.active { background: #40d47e !important }
.btn.active:after { content: '✅'; color: #333 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="text-center">
  <h3>Não sei se todos estão ativados ou desativados</h3>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
      <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked>Android
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
      <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">Windows
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
      <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">iOS
    </label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <h3>Não sei se esta selecionado dois e um não esta  selecionado</h3>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked>Android
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">Windows
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off">iOS
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ainda assim, seria importante diferenciar visualmente o componente que permite uma marca individual (o check-box) daquele que permite múltimas marcas. Poder-se-ia deixar a cargo do usuário descobrir isso interagindo (o que não costuma ser um problema grave, uma vez que a escolha comumente não é tomada imediatamente), mas uma indicação qualquer é útil.

Uma alternativa é fazer com que os botões selecionados também se afundem, e no radio-button ter sempre um deles inicialmente selecionado (isto é, afundado). Essa mesma alternativa pode ser implementada só com a marca, fazendo sempre uma já começar selecionada. Intuitivamente o usuário vai perceber a diferença porque o check-box com vários itens pode começar com todos deselecionados e o radio-button não. Ou você pode, se tiver habilidades para desenho, alterar a forma dos botões para fazê-los ficarem diferenciados (mais circulares, por exemplo) e assim estabelecer uma convenção própria.

Comment: Foi mal pela resposta opinativa, depois tento reformular com algo melhor.

Comment: Eu acho que algumas perguntas de UX são ótimas e se procurar é um tema bem aceito pela comunidade, votei por deixar aberta e +1 pelo ótimo exemplo. Achei o checked uma grande sacada.

Comment: Ótima resposta. +1 Concordo plenamente. Mas eu sugeriria fazer *também* a diferenciação entre o que é check-box e o que é radio-button (talvez colocando uma borda móvel de linha dupla ao redor da opção selecionada no radio?). Se vc achou que a resposta ficou opinativa, eu posso ajudar com alguns detalhes dos *porquês* de se fazer como vc sugere. Se me permitir, eu edito a sua resposta para adicionar tais detalhes (e não tem problema, pode ficar com a reputação hahaha).

Comment: @LuizVieira eu ia sugerir a mesma coisa, mas eu estava esperando um retorno do autor da pergunta.

Comment: Claro @LuizVieira, se não tiver problema para você, não há pra mim. **:)**

Comment: Ok Renan, farei isso assim que possível. :)

Comment: @renan ótimo exemplo, tenho uma dúvida, se você sobrescrever as regras do `btn`, irá sobrescrever para todos os `inputs/buttons` com ela, não seria possível apenas editar aqueles que são checkbox/radios?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Há vários seletores nas CSS que ajudam a selecionar um elemento de grupo específico. Por exemplo, [somente *checkboxes* com classe `.btn`](https://jsfiddle.net/rnbr/qpj55eph/).

Comment: Renan, eu fiz umas edições pra tentar ajudar. Por favor, veja se gostou, e pode ficar a vontade pra editar e melhorar. Se você, que já manja de bootstrap, tiver interesse e disponibilidade pra fazer mais um exemplo de código com distinções no radio-button, seria bacana também. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira Deu aula, ficou muito boa. Eu pensei em transformar a resposta em Wiki, o que acha?

Comment: +1 Porque ficou fofo. :P Mas, acredito que o problema esteja mais nas cores do que no fato de existir ou não o ✅.

Comment: Obrigado. Não acho que precise transformar em Wiki. Não é algo assim tão canônico. :)